# Python3 - I do not want to print the Javascript code with BeautifulSoup

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url  = 'http://www.link.com'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
for x in (soup.find_all(True,text=re.compile(r'text on the page', re.I))):
print (x, '\n')
```

Now when I run it, it prints out some javascript which I do not know why (I want to see some text not some script). My questions is: How can I get rid of the javascript everytime I want to scrape data from the web?

Output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++)   x=d.forms[i][n];
for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;   i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
//-->
</script> 

<td align="left" class="template_title" height="50" valign="bottom" width="535"><div style="padding-bottom:9px;">4</div></td>
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of the output you're seeing? Might give a clearer idea of what's happening.

Comment: @TomElliott It took me ages to paste correctly the code :P It is in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`script` element is a legitimate element in the DOM. You can, though, tell `find_all()` not to return you `script` tags:

```
soup.find_all(lambda elm: elm and elm.name != 'script', text=re.compile(r'text on the page', re.I))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, could you explain me why is it still printing script even tho it doesn't appear to be text?

Comment: Sorry to bother, but do you remember the documentation where you found the information about lambda and tags to not print?

Comment: @bob sure, here is a good information about the use of functions in `bs4`: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function.